# What this icon is called?

Tags: flutter, icons

I am trying to find the name of the icon used in this navigation bar "election" or "add election" ?
or any other similar icons?
thanks in advance!!

[image: BottomNavigationBar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact match for those icons on Material Design Icons or Cupertino Icons.

If you got the SVG versions of those icons, you can still use https://www.fluttericon.com/ to create a custom font that will display your icons.

You can actually find more informations on how to do this on [this medium article](https://medium.com/codechai/how-to-use-custom-icons-in-flutter-834a079d977)

Answer (score 1):

You could use FontAwesome https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter

For the first icon: grip-horizontal
For the second icon: plus-circle

Or for the second icon you could (if you have something like illustrator) get the SVG from the both icons and combine them into one svg. And then like @BLKKKBVSIK is saying create your own custom font trough [www.fluttericon.com](http://www.fluttericon.com)